# A way to emulate slow internet on Mac

Tags: macos

I want to test how my web application behaves when internet is very slow. I want to limit speed and/or ping on OS-level (I'm running OS X 10.10), or cross-browser.

An option could be a hosting that serves files slowly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use "Network Link Conditioner" which is available from Apple in the package "Hardware IO Tools for Xcode" on the [downloads site](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action).

When downloaded, simply double click the "Network Link Conditioner.prefPane" which installs a preference pane. Then go to "Preferences" and setup your "bad" network.

Answer (score 0):

you can simulate a slow connection from inside your browser.
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24066/how-to-simulate-slow-internet-connections-on-the-mac